# How does buttermilk affect a waffle recipe?

Tags: ingredient-selection, buttermilk

A lot of waffle recipes call for buttermilk and some claim its addition makes superior waffles. Apart from thickening the batter and giving it a slightly acidic flavour, does its addition do anything else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The role of buttermilk in most recipes, including waffles, is to provide acid into the reaction with baking soda to cause it to 'rise' more. The thickness helps the batter retain the air pockets that the acid + baking soda creates when heat is applied, resulting in a 'lighter fluffier' waffle.

Comment: Buttermilk really does amazing things to pancakes and waffles.

Comment: ...and biscuits.

Comment: So it's like eating a fluffy little science fair volcano?

Comment: You're right about that. Using buttermilk, I notice my buttermilk waffles are thicker and firmer (and stay that way) straight out of the waffle iron compared with waffles made with milk which are softer with a tendency to collapse slightly once removed from the iron.